# Wkhtmltopdf can't create pdf file(From the web page with "exec")

Tags: javascript, php, wkhtmltopdf

With Command below, I can create `pdf` file,

> `wkhtmltopdf "https://www.yahoo.co.jp" yahoo.pdf`

but from the web page I made, can't create `pdf` file.
The code is this.and this is only code when the page calls by click.

> `exec("wkhtmltopdf 'www.yahoo.co.jp' yahoo.pdf");`

If I add `--disable-javascript`, It can create `pdf`.
But I need `JavaScript` functions.

> `system("wkhtmltopdf 'www.yahoo.co.jp' yahoo.pdf 2> result.txt");`

by this code. I got two results
With `--disable-javascript`

```
Loading pages (1/6)
[> ] 0%

[======> ] 10%

[=============> ] 23%

[=================> ] 29%

[==================> ] 31%

[===================> ] 33%

[=====================> ] 36%

[======================> ] 38%

[============================================================] 100%

Counting pages (2/6) 

[============================================================] Object 1 of 1

Resolving links (4/6) 

[============================================================] Object 1 of 1

Loading headers and footers (5/6) 

Printing pages (6/6)

[> ] Preparing

[============================================================] Page 1 of 1
```

and without disabling `JavaScript`

```
Loading pages (1/6)


[> ] 0%

[======> ] 10%
```

these words are written in `result.txt`

Comment: So what's actually wrong? Wrong output/no output/errors?

Comment: No output.(pdf file)

Comment: with --disable-javascript,pdf file has created(but no javascript).but without --disable-javascript,pdf hasn't created.